# Mysql error on sql like operator rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I get an error

> Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '%booked%)

How can I solve this?

**Model**

```
scope :with_type, lambda { |type|
   where("LOWER(reservations.message) LIKE %#{type}%")
}
```

Sql statement on server

```
SELECT  `reservations`.*
FROM `reservations`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `reservations`.`from_id`
WHERE (`users`.`access_level_id` != 1)
AND `reservations`.`id_to` IS NULL
AND (LOWER(reservations.message) LIKE %booked%)
ORDER BY reservations.created_at desc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL's `LIKE` operator takes strings on both sides so the SQL you want to produce is:

```
LOWER(reservations.message) LIKE '%booked%'
```

i.e. `%booked%` in single quotes. The easiest way to do that is to use a placeholder in your scope:

```
scope :with_type, ->(type) { where('LOWER(reservations.message) LIKE ?', "%#{type}%") }
```

That puts the string interpolation in Ruby and hands that string to `where` to quote it so you're also protected from injection issues.